# Error in LettuceConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, lettuce

Hi I'am trying to  use spring-session-data-redis but its throwing an exception,
I'am using springboot 2.0.4 and springRedis Data with lettuce (both are latest vesrion).

```
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name'org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/netelixir/config/RedisHttpSessionConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/lettuce/core/AbstractRedisClient
```

my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.xyz.emailreports</groupId>
<artifactId>EmailReports</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>LxrEmailReports</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
         <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
              <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <type>jar</type>
         </dependency>
    </dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

This is my RedisHttpSessionConfig.java class where I wrote code for RedisData

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;

@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisHttpSessionConfig  {  
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }

}
```

here is my SecurityConfig.java class

```
package com.xyz.config;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

    import com.netelixir.service.UserSecurityService;
    import org.springframework.session.web.http.HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver;
    import org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionIdResolver;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Autowired
        private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

        private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
        }

        private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/user/**"
        };

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

         @Bean
        public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
            return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken(); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `io.lettuce:lettuce-core` as a dependency should fix the exception.